# When can we leave out "it is" in formal writings?

Tags: grammar

Are these two following sentences correct and have the same meaning?

(a) Despite it is an appealing protocol, it has some problems.

(b) Despite appealing, the protocol has some problems

Comment: Despite it **being** an appealing protocol...

Comment: I think you want to replace "despite" with "although". As DivideByZero said, your example sentences are not grammatical.  "Although" makes them both grammatical. That highlights your question about dropping "it is".

Comment: "Despite being an appealing protocol, ..." is also correct (without the first "it").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not grammatically correct:

> Despite it is an appealing protocol, it has some problems.

However, this is a grammatically correct sentence (and what I would guess you were trying to say):

> Even though it is an appealing protocol, it has some problems.

This doesn't make much sense without context but I guess it could be what you are trying to say if the protocol describes a method of appealing. **This is important - the protocol is the one doing the appealing.**

---

Option B is  grammatically correct, but it is fairly vague and means something entirely different.

> Despite appealing, the protocol has some problems.

Is the same as saying:

> Even though the protocol is being appealed, it still has problems.

In this case somebody **(a person, not the protocol)** is the one performing an appeal.

---

I am not sure which of these two you are attempting to say because there is no context. However, the sentences definitely do not mean the same thing, and sentence A is not grammatically correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to first give some credit to the protocol and then criticize it. So, it wanted to say: even though it is an interesting protocol, it has some problems. I used appealing instead of interesting.

Comment: @Ay. Appealed is not the same as interesting. An appeal is something that you would submit to contest a traffic ticket, or maybe use to apply for citizenship in a country. Appealed is past tense of appeal. Appealing is the current tense verb of appeal, which is why I was unsure of what you were trying to say.

The word you are looking for is "appealing", which means good and/or pretty.
You could say "even though it is an appealing protocol, it has some problems".
I would recommend using this sentence, it seems to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment-- please have a closer look at my question, I've used "appealing"

Comment: @Ay. I have already looked at your question very closely. The issue is that "appealing" can mean you are trying to appeal something (when you use it as an verb, like "I am appealing this traffic ticket"), or it can mean that something is good (when using it as adjective to describe a noun). Make sure you are using it as an adjective. 

I still believe that you should use the sentence "even though it is an appealing protocol, it has some problems". You can never say "despite it is" - it doesn't work grammatically and it makes "appealing" sound like a verb (which you don't want in this case).

Comment: thanks very much!

Comment: can i say instead: even though appealing, the protocol has problems.

Comment: If you want the sentence in that form I would recommend "Even though it is appealing, the protocol has problems". The "it is" part helps readers understand your sentence.

Comment: Here's another idea - "Although this is an appealing solution, there are a few issues with this approach".
Just giving you some options to choose between :)

Comment: Despite **it being** an appealing protocol, it has some problems.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the answers and suggestions made already, so I'll simply offer a few variations and leave it.

```
Despite its appeal, the protocol has problems.
While appealing, the protocol has problems.
Appealing as it may be, the protocol has problems.
```

Comment: I guess all of your examples mean the same as Option B, I made this comment in case some learners probably don't realize it easily.